# Public debt of European countries, by year

Tags: data-request, government-debt

Where can I find lists with public debt of European countries such as the UK, by year? (or by fiscal year)

If there are such lists on Eurostat but only for the last 10 year or so, I would like to have longer lists, for each country in part.

Later edit: If possible, having both the amount in Euros and in percentage of GDP, would be great. Like for example this list for Spain: http://www.datosmacro.com/deuda/espana

If you know lists for a single country, please mention them. For example if you are from Germany and you have links with such a list for Germany, from the National Institute of Statistics or another site, please let me know about it, I'll vote your answer.

Comment: The IMF should have the best data on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IMF created its Historical Public Debt Database a few years back; that should do the trick for you. It's described in [this paper](https://www.imf.org/external/pubs/cat/longres.cfm?sk=24332.0), with annual data from 2012 back to as far as the late-1800s for some countries. You could pair that with the IMF/World Bank [Quarterly Public Sector Debt](http://datatopics.worldbank.org/debt/home) statistics.

Comment: Can you indicate me where are the papers for UK for example? Or do I have to buy them? The World Bank data seems to be yearly, not quarterly. Also doesn't include many countries, doesn't have EU countries. The table has a lot of rows, which one is the actual public debt? For example Turkey 2005 - http://datatopics.worldbank.org/debt/ids/country/TUR - External debt stocks (172,130.5) or Long-term external debt (118,407.8)

Comment: I assure you that the quarterly public sector debt data is quarterly and includes EU countries. Please spend the time to figure out how to navigate the website yourself before asking about it. Go here: http://databank.worldbank.org/data/reports.aspx?source=quarterly-public-sector-debt and select the countries, series, and time frame you want. For earlier periods, use the annual data at the other link I provided.

Answer (score 5):

Would you be satisfied with a graph of the last 20 years? 
Is yes, you can use [Google Data Explorer](https://www.google.hu/publicdata/explore?ds=ds22a34krhq5p_&met_y=gd_pc_gdp&idim=country:uk:de:fr&hl=en&dl=en#!ctype=l&strail=false&bcs=d&nselm=h&met_y=gd_pc_gdp&scale_y=lin&ind_y=false&rdim=country_group&idim=country:uk&ifdim=country_group&hl=en_US&dl=en&ind=false). 
It seems to rely on Eurostat as well, so the data is probably available from them somewhere.

Comment: I would like to have data for more than that but it's surely a good start! Thanks.